# uninstall wireshark Version 1.12.7 from ubuntu trusty tar

Tags: uninstall

I installed this version {version 1.12.7} of `Wireshark` and its not working as i want it. I compiled it as directed from the tutorial.

1. it works only as root user and the commands to change that doesn't work.

I just want to uninstall it. DON'T WANT IT ANYMORE
I have used

```
sudo apt-get remove wireshark
sudo apt-get purge wireshark
```

none is working. When I type `wireshark` on the terminal it still runs normally 
I fear using the older version will cause me problems on GNS3.

I need help Linux gurus

Comment: please edit your question and add output of `apt-cache policy wireshark
` and also how you installed ? via PPA or .deb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove a compiled version in the same way as a deb package.

1. If you no longer have the source code, download the source code again
2. Compile Wireshark again, and **don't** install
3. Install `checkinstall`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
4. Install, **yes install** via

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   Why? `checkinstall` creates a deb package and installs the package and overwrites in this way all installed files of your earlier installation via `sudo make install`
5. Remove

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove wireshark
   ```

And in the future, use `checkinstall` to install your self-compiled code.